# Use of .digest() in hashing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the use of .digest() in this statement?  Why do we use it ? I searched on google ( and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) also) but still I am not able to figure it out.

```
train_hashes = [hashlib.sha1(x).digest() for x in train_dataset]
```

What I found is that it convert to string. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: That's... the output. It's your hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.digest()` method returns the actual *digest* the hash is designed to produce.

It is a separate method because the hashing API is designed to accept data in multiple pieces:

```
hash = hashlib.sha1()
for chunk in large_amount_of_data:
    hash.update(chunk)
final_digest = hash.digest()
```

The above code creates a hashing object without passing any initial data in, then uses the [`hash.update()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) to put chunks of data in in a loop. This helps avoid having to all of the data into memory all at once, so you can hash anything between 1 byte and the entire Google index, if you ever had access to something that large.

If `hashlib.sha1(x)` produced the digest *directly* you could never add additional data to hash first. Moreover, there is also an alternative method of accessing the digest, as a hexadecimal string using the [`hash.hexdigest()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) (equivalent to `hash.digest().hex()`, but more convenient).

The code you found uses the fact that the constructor of the hash object also accepts data; since that's the all of the data that you wanted to hash you can call `.digest()` immediately.

The [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) covers it this way:

> There is one constructor method named for each type of hash. All return a hash object with the same simple interface. For example: use `sha256()` to create a SHA-256 hash object. You can now feed this object with bytes-like objects (normally bytes) using the `update()` method. **At any point you can ask it for the digest of the concatenation of the data fed to it so far using the `digest()` or `hexdigest()` methods.**

(bold emphasis mine).